# To compare two independent image coordinate lists with same scale but coordinate-grid having some rotation and shift

Tags: python

I am in possession of two independent coordinate lists (position of stars in (x,y)) with one having some amount of rotation (but the distance between two matched points will be approximately the same in both the lists). The two lists will mostly contain the same stars, but a few of them could be different.

for example,

```
list1  
2691    2968
1772    1580
4020    1479
3836    1920
2045    2591
2202    1945
```

and

```
list2
1648    1807
2568    3195
3898    1705
3712    2147
2078    2171
1921    2818
```

If you consider the above two lists, the same star pairs are,

```
(2691,2968) & (2568,3195)
(1772,1580) & (1648,1807)
(4020,1479) & (3898,1705)
(3836,1920) & (3712,2147)      
(2045,2591) & (1921,2818)      
(2202,1945) & (2078,2171)
```

How does one achieve this sort of matching? One idea that I have is that make many triangles and compare the area.

I would prefer python to do this and I need as output only the matched array of star positions existing in both lists.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found a way to do it. I wouldn't call it optimised, though.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations as mutate

sigma_c = 1.5
def reject_outliers(data, m=sigma_c):
    return data[abs(data - np.mean(data)) < m * np.std(data)]

list1 = np.genfromtxt("1.coo")
list2 = np.genfromtxt("2.coo")

x1,y1 = zip(*list1)
x2,y2 = zip(*list2)

compare_value = 10000**2
for i, j in zip(mutate(x1), mutate(y1)):
    diff = (np.array(x2)-np.array(i))
    stddev = np.std(reject_outliers(diff))
    if stddev <= compare_value:
        compare_value = stddev
        mutant_x1 = map(int,i)
        mutant_y1 = map(int,j)
        difference_array = map(int,diff)


print(zip(mutant_x1, mutant_y1))
print(zip(map(int,x2), map(int,y2)))
print("with difference array (X coo):")
print(difference_array)
```