# Comparing two lists of stellar x-y coordinates to find matching objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two .txt files that contain the x and y pixel coordinates of thousands of stars in an image. These two different coordinate lists were the products of different data processing methods, which result in slightly different x and y values for the same object.

File 1 *the id_out is arbitrary

> ```
> id_out  x_out       y_out         m_out
> 0       803.6550    907.0910     -8.301
> 1       700.4570    246.7670     -8.333
> 2       802.2900    894.2130     -8.344
> 3       894.6710    780.0040     -8.387
> ```

File 2

> ```
> xcen      ycen      mag           merr
> 31.662    37.089    22.759        0.387
> 355.899   37.465    19.969        0.550
> 103.079   37.000    20.839        0.847
> 113.500   38.628    20.966        0.796
> ```

The objects listed in the .txt files are not organized in a way that allows me to identify the same object in both files. So, I thought for every object in file 1, which has fewer objects than file 2, I would impose a test to find the star match between file 1 and file 2. For every star in file 1, I want to find the star in file 2 that has the closest match to x-y coordinates using the distance formula:
distance= sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) within some tolerance of distance that I can change. Then print onto a master list the x1, y1, x2, y2, m_out, mag, and merr parameters in the file.

Here is the code I have so far, but I am not sure how to arrive at a working solution.

```
#/usr/bin/python
import pandas
import numpy as np

xcen_1 = np.genfromtxt('file1.txt', dtype=float, usecols=1)
ycen_1 = np.genfromtxt('file1.txt', dtype=float, usecols=2)
mag1 = np.genfromtxt('file1.txt', dtype=float, usecols=3)

xcen_2 = np.genfromtxt('file2.txt', dtype=float, usecols=0)
ycen_2 = np.genfromtxt('file2.txt', dtype=float, usecols=1)
mag2 = np.genfromtxt('file2.txt', dtype=float, usecols=2)
merr2 = np.genfromtxt('file2.txt', dtype=float, usecols=3)

tolerance=10.0

i=0
file=open('results.txt', 'w+')
file.write("column names")
for i in len(xcen_1):
    dist=np.sqrt((xcen_1[i]-xcen_2[*])^2+(ycen_1[i]-ycen_2[*]^2))
    if dist < tolerance:
        f.write(i, xcen_1, ycen_1, xcen_2, ycen_2, mag1, mag2, merr2)
    else:
        pass
    i=i+1
file.close
```

The code doesn't work as I don't know how to implement that every star in file 2 must be run through the test, as indicated by the * index (which comes from idl, in which I am more versed). Is there a solution for this logic, as opposed to the thinking in this case:

[To compare two independent image coordinate lists with same scale but coordinate-grid having some rotation and shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856385/to-compare-two-independent-image-coordinate-lists-with-same-scale-but-coordinate)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas Dataframes`. Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
# files containing the x and y pixel coordinates and other information
df_file1=pd.read_csv('file1.txt',sep='\s+')
df_file2=pd.read_csv('file2.txt',sep='\s+')
join=[]
for i in range(len(df_file1)):
    for j in range(len(df_file2)):
        dis=((df_file1['x_out'][i]-df_file2['xcen'][j])**2+(df_file1['y_out'][i]-df_file2['ycen'][j])**2)**0.5
        if dis<10:
            join.append({'id_out': df_file1['id_out'][i], 'x_out': df_file1['x_out'][i], 'y_out':df_file1['y_out'][i], 
                         'm_out':df_file1['m_out'][i],'xcen':df_file2['xcen'][j],'ycen':df_file2['ycen'][j],
                         'mag':df_file2['mag'][j],'merr':df_file2['merr'][j]})

df_join=pd.DataFrame(join) 
df_join.to_csv('results.txt', sep='\t')
```

Comment: That code gave me a Runtime error. "parse2.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars". I can't see any issue about negative number or division by zero. In this case, j > i. Could that be the reason?

Comment: `j>i` shouldn't be causing a problem. You might want to check the line at which the problem is occurring. Put a print statement after the `join.append..` line. Like so: `print (df_file1['id_out'][i])`, to identify if the numbers on that particular line look okay.

Comment: The x or y values are 0 < x < 500 or 0 < y < 5000, meaning that the difference < 5000. I can't imagine python not being able to calculate that.

Comment: There was a typo in the above code - in the distance calculation change `-` to `+`. Check if that is affecting your result. If you still encounter that issue, check this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html. You can put in this line `np.seterr('ignore')` to ignore the lines causing trouble. For more detailed information try other options instead of `ignore`.

Comment: parse2.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  dis=((df_file1['x_out'][i]-df_file2['xcen'][j])**2-(df_file1['y_out'][i]-df_file2['ycen'][j])**2)**0.5: It's in the calculation.

Comment: Change `-` to `+`, like so: ((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)**0.5

Comment: The problem would have arisen because the square root of a negative number might have been called.

Comment: I didn't notice the - to + until you mentioned it, but that was the problem. Code ran successfully, if not a bit slowly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.